# htaccess redirect to https all pages except one

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, yii

I'm using Yii framework. I want to redirect all pages on the site from HTTP to HTTPS except this one **domain.com/clip/create**.

Following code redirects all pages to HTTPS:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```

I modified that code to add exception for one page and it doesn't work properly.
It works for all pages on the site, but on address **domain.com/clip/create** it redirects to **https://domain.com/index.php**
My code is below:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/clip/create
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} ^on$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/clip/create
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R,L]    

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You want to remove the "https" part of the second redirect, (and you probably don't need the `!-f` and `!-d` checks either):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} ^on$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/clip/create
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R,L]    
# no "s" here ---------^
```

---

It's probably because of your Yii controller. You'll need to prevent another redirect *after* the request is routed to the `index.php` controller. Add this to the very top (before the redirects):

```
RewriteRule index\.php - [L]
```

Comment: It was a typo, I don't have https there and it does not work even without !-f and !-d. I edited my question.

Comment: @kromol wait, is `/clip/create` a directory that actually exists?

Comment: @kromol and the `RewriteRule . index.php` rule, that's something you need for Yii, right? It's not just copied and pasted from somewhere else? Because I add those rules to a blank htaccess file and it works fine.

Comment: `/clip/create` is not a directory. It is controller with action. There is file `ClipController.php` and it has a function named `actionCreate`

Comment: @kromol Dunno then, everything works fine if I include `RewriteRule index\.php - [L]` at the top, and it's broken just like you said when I remove that line. No idea why it's still not working for you but works fine for me. Maybe it's not the htaccess rules that's doing the redirecting.

Comment: Strange, because it doesn't work only for that page. Anyway thank you for help, I'll continue looking for what causes this issue.

Comment: @kromol you wouldn't happen to have some other mechanism (like a plugin or something your hosting service is doing) that is forcing https, would you?

Comment: No,I don't have any other mechanism that is forcing https

Answer (score 0):

i'm terrible with htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/clip/create [OR]
RewriteRule ^/directory(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/directory$1 [L,R]
```

got rules from [here](http://www.michaelbarton.name/2009/12/13/forcing-ssl-with-phpmyadmin/)

Answer (score 0):

clear your browser cache ! I faced many of these issues while I was working on switching connection type between HTTP and HTTPS , and then I found ,after a lot of searching and trying, that Firefox and chrome caches 301 and 302 error codes .

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/clip/create
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```